# how to place .jpg file in .xib file?

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0

In my current application,I have to design a login page.which contains username and password textfields.but my requirement is to insert image(instead of submit button).can  anyone give a clear idea about this task?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a UIImage instead of a UIButton. Instructions here - http://iphonesdkpro.com/iOS+SDK+Using+a+UIImage+as+a+Button+iPhone+SDK

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that the jpg is imported into your project in Xcode.
2. Launch Interface Builder with your .xib.
3. Create the UIButton. Click on it and press Cmd-1 to show the button's Attributes.
4. Change the button Type to Custom.
5. Click on the Image element in the palette and choose the jpg image you want to use,
   **OR**
   If you prefer to have text over the image, instead change the Background element to your image.